# How to deploy truffle contracts to Rinkebey?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, metamask, truffle-config, rinkeby

What are the parameters that I have to specify to be able to deploy solidity contracts using Truffle in the config file? I am using Metamask to store test ether and have a unique mnemonic to define this in the config file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your truffle.js:

```
module.exports = {
  rpc: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8545'
  },
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
    },
    rinkeby: {
      network_id: 4,
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8545,
      gas: 4000000
    }
  }
}
```

then after starting and syncing geth to look at the rinkyby test network like:

https://www.rinkeby.io/ -the connect yourself section or

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth

[and more info here](https://gist.github.com/cryptogoth/10a98e8078cfd69f7ca892ddbdcf26bc)
you could:

`truffle console --network rinkeby`

or

`truffle migrate --network rinkeby`

which lets you interact with your local running/syncing rinkeby node.